# Find an $M_k$ for the weierstrass $M$-test-- hint wanted.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

For $|z|\leqslant r<1$, find $M_k$ so that:

$$\frac{|z^k|}{|z^k+1|} \leqslant M_k$$

for each $k$, and $\sum M_k$ converges.

This is for the Weierstrass $M$-test. For some reason, I can't really get it straight in my head-- the numerator is clearly bounded above by $r^k$, which is promising for convergence, but the denominator is giving me trouble. The geometry tells me that $|z^k+1| \geqslant (1-r)/2$, which would suffice for my purposes, but I can't see how to get there, and I feel like there could be a more straightforward method. Could someone give me a **hint**?

Comment: what does applying the reverse triangle inequality to $|z^k+1|$ give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|1+x| \ge 1-|x|$ (Reverse triangle inequality).

---

Also note that $1+x$ need not be positive, or even scalar-valued. The triangle inequality holds in every normed vector space.

Comment: Oh wow, I had been staring at the reverse triangle inequality, but it didn't occur to me that the interior of the $|-|$ was positive. So this is just $|1+z^k| \geqslant 1-|z^k| \geqslant 1-r$?

Comment: @William: That will do! The key is that because $0 \le r < 1$, the bound $1/(1-r^k) \le 1/(1-r)$ holds for all $k$.